# fork(), child process not dumping core, parent process does fine

Tags: c, fork

"ulimit -c unlimited" has been done. Here is the code:

```
main()
{
        do
        {
            pid_t pid = fork();
            int stat_loc;
            if(pid < 0)
                exit(1);
            else if(pid > 0)
            {
                waitpid(pid, &stat_loc, 0);
                sleep(5);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        while(1);

        assert(0);
}
```

If I replace sleep(5) with assert(0) the parent process dumps core.

Comment: It works for me on Linux kernel 4.17, glibc 2.27, amd64.

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  So it does not compile!   the function `main()` always has a return type of `int`, not a blank

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: suggest replacing: `if(pid < 0)
                exit(1);`  with `if(pid < 0)  { perror( "fork failed" );
                exit(1); }`  So the user/you will know why the call to `fork()` failed

Comment: The code is just pseudo code to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Calling assert(0) on a debug build of your application [should cause an abort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/):

> If the argument expression of this macro with functional form compares equal to zero (i.e., the expression is false), a message is written to the standard error device and abort is called, terminating the program execution.

What are you actually looking to do here? It looks like there may be a problem with your forking logic. Typically you test to see if pid == 0 to see if you're in the child process and pid > 0 to see if you're in the parent process, [like this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/):

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    // child process because return value zero
    printf("Hello from Child!\n");
} else if (pid > 0) {
    // parent process because return value non-zero.
    printf("Hello from Parent!\n");
} else {
    printf("Error occurred.\n");
}
```

In your question you're checking for > 0 and < 0.

Edit: Added error checking branch.

Comment: this answer is misleading.  Because the function: `fork()` has three kinds of returns 1) <0 means an error occurred.  2) == 0 means in the child process 3) > 0 means in the parent process.  Code needs to check all three conditions as act accordingly

Comment: Agreed. Modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: assert(0) has been deliberately called to make the application dump core. The code is just for testing. The forking logic is fine - the parent process will continue inside the loop and the child will execute assert(0). Please note that the parent core dumps without a problem if i replace sleep(5) with assert(0).